# Java XSLT transformer with default namepace without xmlns

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I'm working on some Java code that takes XML in DOM, with no namespace prefixes declared, yet each element has a namespace of `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`. (This is equivalent to the HTML DOM a browser gets.) The code uses the following to serialize the DOM to a string:

```java
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
```

The resulting string looks like this:

```html
…
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
…
```

Note the presence of `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`, which the DOM did not have. In terms of XML, this is entirely correct: if the element uses a namespace (even without a prefix), the namespace must be declared on that element or a an ancestor element; and this being the document element, the namespace declaration must go here.

However HTML is a little different story. The [WHATWG HTML5 Specification § 2.1.3 XML compatibility](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#xml) says:

> To ease migration from HTML to XML, user agents conforming to this specification will place elements in HTML in the http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml namespace, at least for the purposes of the DOM and CSS.

In other words, HTML browsers will assume a namespace of `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace even without a namespace declaration. And typical clean HTML will not have a namespace declaration. And for this particular use case, a namespace declaration is not required.

**How can I tell a transformer not to add a default namespace declaration for the document?** Alternatively, how can I remove it later without resorting to brute force such as regular expression matching?

Internally the `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl` creates a `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO` instance, which eventually calls `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri, boolean shouldFlush)`. Here is the "offending" code that adds the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on the document element:

```java
if (EMPTYSTRING.equals(prefix))
{
  name = "xmlns";
  addAttributeAlways(XMLNS_URI, name, name, "CDATA", uri, false);
}
```

But to be more precise, I see that the actual adding of the attribute is done by `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.AttributesImplSerializer.addAttribute(String uri, String local, String qname, String type, String val)`. This class extends `org.xml.sax.helpers.AttributesImpl` and implements `org.xml.sax.Attributes`.

Is there some way I can splice my own customized `Attributes` implementation into a `Transformer`, so that I can check this special case and forgo adding the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` attribute in the appropriate context?

I suppose as a last resort, is there a way to tell the `Transformer` to be namespace aware, but never to add `xmlns` declarations that weren't already in the DOM?

(For those who insist in asking where I got a DOM with an HTML namespace without an `xmlns` declaration, it's irrelevant. Let's assume that I constructed an XML DOM instance programmatically but want to output it as "clean" HTML5, so I remove the default `xmlns` attribute, but the `Transformer` is putting it back.)

Comment: I don't understand why your DOM nodes would be in the XHTML namespace unless someone created the elements in that namespace, either by parsing/loading some XHTML which has the namespace (perhaps in the XHTML DTD) or which did use createElementNS with the XHTML namespace. Otherwise I don't see why the Transformer would output a namespace.

Comment: Martin, did you read the link I provided to the WHATWG HTML5 specification? If I parse an HTML5 document to DOM, I need to put it in the HTML namespace even without a namespace declaration. (You're getting distracted by how I got the DOM, which is slightly irrelevant in relation to the question.) For example go to `https://example.com` and in the browser enter the snippet `document.body.firstElementChild.namespaceURI`. You'll see it gets the HTML namespace. When you say "XHTML namespace" maybe you're thinking in terms of the obsolete XHTML 2 eons ago. But HTML5 gets the same namespace.

Comment: "I don't understand why your DOM nodes would be in the XHTML namespace …" To answer your question more directly (even though slightly irrelevant), a library is parsing HTML5 documents as a browser would and presenting a DOM to the application as a browser would. But printing back out the DOM I want it as HTML, which means I don't want the `xmlns` declaration for the default namespace. (I'm fully aware that the `Transformer` is working "correctly" in terms of XML, but it isn't giving me the serialized form of HTML5 I prefer, and as is overwhelmingly used in the wild.)

Comment: But what HTML5 decrees or browsers implement doesn't matter if you work with the Java JAXP stack for DOM and XSLT, still don't see why in that stack you would have an Element node being serialized with a namespace declaration without being in a namespace. If you want HTML5 serialization for a DOM tree then perhaps https://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/ has that, I am currently not sure of its state of development and whether the u.validator.htmlparser.tools.HTML2HTML does what you want, but I suspect so.

Comment: Like I said, where I got the DOM is irrelevant, and if we go down that road we're going to get sidetracked with a long, off-topic discussion. But since you insist … I'm actually fixing a bug in [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/), which is exactly like Validator.nu except it accepts dirty HTML as in the wild, and presents it to the application in DOM as a browser would. Specifically it is [jsoup issue #1837](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1837). You can go read all the gritty details (but don't say I didn't warn you). When you come back here we'll be right back to the issue we started with. 

Comment: "I am currently not sure of its state of development and whether [insert some library here] does what you want, but I suspect so." Ah, no offense, but I've gotten this response a gazillion times here (and with your experience on Stack Overflow, you probably have, too). Whenever I get that response, I can be sure that 1) the library has long been abandoned, and 2) it does not do what I want, and what it does do is buggy as heck because someone made assumptions instead of reading the spec. That's just been my experience anyway.  That's why I'm trying to help jsoup, which is not yet abandoned.

Comment: Good luck fixing something in the world of the "soup" parsers or serializers.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Now, back to the question, which is very focused on the behavior of `Transformer`. The DOM I have is not "soup" at all. It is a completely normal XML DOM, except that it is missing a single `xmlns` namespace declaration, which the `Transformer` adds. Can you help me answer the question of how to tell the `Transformer` not to add the `xmlns` attribute on the document element?

Comment: See this discussion of jsoup and the source of the DOM has completely missed the point of the question.  Forget jsoup. Let's say I construct the XML DOM programmatically, and I want to output a serialization without the the default `xmlns` attribute because I want pretty HTML5. It's the same issue, and has nothing to do with soup.

Comment: Well, if you have namespaces and want to get rid of them write a stylesheet that does that instead of relying on the identity transformer. Serialization according to (some state of) the HTML5 rules is supported in XSLT 3, anyway.

Comment: "Well, if you have namespaces and want to get rid of them …". I don't want to get rid of the namespaces! I want to prevent the `Transformer` from adding an `xmlns` attribute for the default namespace on the document element. "… write a stylesheet that does that instead of relying on the identity transformer." I'm working on someone else's open-source project, so my options are limited, and I have my own projects to work on. That's why this is a focused question. "… HTML5 … XSLT 3 …" That sounds promising. Is it available in Java 8?

Comment: Yes, all current Saxon HE versions (the supported releases are 11 and 10) work with Java 8. But don't get too excited, if there is an XHTML namespace then serialization by default is using the `xhtml` method, which produces XHTML5 servable as text/html, but surely will keep the XHTML namespace.

Comment: "… servable as text/html …" Well I'm sure that a serialization is servable as `text/html` even if it includes the `xmlns` attribute. That's not the issue. The issue is that the library I'm working with has an existing `serialize()` method (not it's real name), and users are accustomed to it returning an HTML _without_ the `xmlns` (which isn't wrong either, for HTML5). So I want to keep from breaking their existing implementation. So we're back to the question: does XSLT 3 allow me to prevent the addition of the default `xmlns` namespace declaration?

Comment: Any XSLT version allows you to strip namespaces, and that is what you seem to want to do. You can do that with XSLT 1 or 2 or 3, but you have to implement that in XSLT, it is certainly not something the identity transformation does.

Comment: "Any XSLT version allows you to strip namespaces …" I would welcome it if you were to post a working solution as an answer! On the other hand, since we both have more important work to do and this isn't even my project, I suspect we will wind up living with the kludge I already [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73920307). 

Answer (score 0):

(Full disclosure: I'm actually fixing a [bug in jsoup](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1837), which is an HTML parser that accepts dirty HTML as in the wild, and presents it to the application in DOM as a browser would. I fixed a bug that didn't assign the HTML namespace even without a namespace declaration. Now the existing `W3CDom.asString(Document doc)` serializer method tries to add the `xmlns` namespace declaration, but users are accustomed to it returning an HTML serialization without the `xmlns` (which for HTML5 isn't wrong). So I'm trying to keep from breaking code that relies on the original "clean" HTML serialization without rewriting the serializer.)

The following is an ugly kludge, but given the constraints I don't see an alternative. I welcome a better approach!

```java
/**
 * Pattern to detect the <code>xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"</code> default namespace
 * declaration when serializing the DOM to HTML. This pattern is "good enough", relying in part
 * on the output of the {@link Transformer} used in the implementation, but is not a complete
 * solution for all the serializations possible; that is, if one constructed an XML string
 * manually, it might be possible to find an obscure variation that this pattern would not
 * match.
 */
static final Pattern HTML_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("<html[^>]*(\\sxmlns=['\"]http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml['\"])");

/**
 * Removes the default <code>xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"</code> HTML namespace
 * declaration if present in the string.
 * 
 * @param html The serialized HTML.
 * @return A string without the default <code>xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"</code> HTML
 *         namespace declaration.
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1837">Issue #1837: Bug: DOM elements not
 *      being placed in (X)HTML namespace.</a>
 */
static String removeDefaultHtmlNamespaceDeclaration(String html) {
    Matcher matcher = HTML_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE_PATTERN.matcher(html);
    if (matcher.find()) {
      html = html.substring(0, matcher.start(1)) + html.substring(matcher.end(1));
    }
    return html;
}
```

Comment: Garret what's the actual issue with outputting a namespace declaration, as a matter of interest? i.e. what is the basis of the requirement to remove it?

Comment: I understand and commend your commitment to not breaking existing clients of the jsoup parser, but what I don't understand is your focus on avoiding the namespace declaration in the _serialization_, when it seems to me that adding the XHTML namespace in the DOM is also a breaking change for jsoup clients which use it to generate a DOM Document rather than a serialization, and will be expecting non-namespaced elements in the DOM. Are you changing the default behaviour of the parser, or do you offer the jsoup client the ability to flag whether or not they want XHTML?

Comment: "Garret what's the actual issue with outputting a namespace declaration, as a matter of interest?" I explained that in this answer. There is an existing serialization method that would change its behavior. Plus users are not expecting an `xmlns` declaration in HTML5, even though they expect the namespace in the DOM.

Comment: "… adding the XHTML namespace in the DOM is also a breaking change for jsoup clients which use it to generate a DOM Document …" But there the previous behavior was a bug. The point of jsoup is to mimic the behavior of a browser, and browsers put HTML elements in the HTML namespace, even in the absence of a namespace declaration. (I feel like I'm repeating myself many times over. I would encourage you to read my comments above and, if you have questions related to jsoup, especially the jsoup bug I referenced.)

Comment: "I explained that in this answer" ... not really. If your explanation had been adequate I wouldn't have asked that question. What I'm trying to get at is: what's the problem that an xmlns would cause the jsoup clients? It seems to me that if the serialization (which you didn't provide in detail) was an XHTML serialization then it should have an xmlns. If it's a non-XML HTML5 serialization then it can be absent. Some more detail here would really help respondents to understand the parameters of the problem.

Comment: Sincerely Conal it sounds like you didn't notice the link to [jsoup issue #1837](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1837) in my answer. Please confirm you have read [jsoup issue #1837](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1837) in full, in particular my [comment there about the serialization method](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/1837#issuecomment-1264408570) you are asking about.

Comment: Garret I had read your entire post here, all your comments, and the entire thread on github. I still don't know what the issue with the xmlns in the serialization is. I assume from your comment on github that there are unit tests that it breaks. Anyway, I've proposed an answer so I'll leave it there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the DOM was created by an application that put the nodes in the XHTML namespace, and therefore the serializer is entirely correct to serialize them in that namespace. From your description, the application did that because it was parsing HTML5 and that's what the HTML5 specification says it should do.

Part of the problem is that you're using an XSLT 1.0 serializer, and XSLT 1.0 predates XHTML and certainly predates HTML5. Unfortunately, just because W3C or WHATWG issues a proclamation doesn't mean that everyone changes their software. You may have better luck using an XSLT 3.0 serializer (Saxon) with the HTML5 output method, but I don't know what your project constraints are.

Comment: "… the serializer is entirely correct to serialize them in that namespace." Yes, the serializer is not doing anything wrong. "Part of the problem is that you're using an XSLT 1.0 serializer …" I agree here as well; in a perfect world I'd rewrite the serializer. But writing HTML5 _without_ the default declaration isn't wrong either. I'm not saying any of the components are working incorrectly; I'm just asking if there is an easy way to change their behavior in order to meet another use case. I outlined the project use case a little more in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73920307).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that since you're relying on some other code to perform the serialization, you will actually need to modify all the elements so that their names are not in the XHTML namespace (if you want a non-kludge solution).

You can recursively traverse all the elements in the document starting from the root element, and use the [`renameNode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#renameNode(org.w3c.dom.Node,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method of the DOM `Document` object to rename them all to have a name which is the same as their old local name, but with no namespace URI.

```java
document.renameNode(element, null, element.getLocalName());
```

You could do the same renaming in XSLT, but I'm guessing you're probably more comfortable doing it in Java.

Comment: Note that the `xmlns` declaration appears on the root element because the element's name has that namespace URI. If you want to avoid the declaration, you will have to rename the root `html` element to a name which doesn't have that namespace URI. And to avoid the same `xmlns` declaration popping up on all the child elements (`head`, `body`) of the root element, you'd have to rename those elements too, and so on ...